# Wrong generated java class name with Buf

Tags: buf

According to [buf doc](https://buf.build/docs/configuration/v1/buf-gen-yaml#java_outer_classname), by default option java_outer_classname converts the weather.proto filename, for example, to WeatherProto.
In my case, it converted it to WeatherOuterClass.

I'm not setting the `option java_outer_classname` in my proto file because I thought it would be handled by default by Buf. Am I missing something?

My buf.gen.yaml looks like:

```yaml
version: v1

managed:
  enabled: true

plugins:
  - plugin: go
    out: v3/golang/gen
    opt: paths=source_relative
```

My buf.yaml looks like:

```yaml
version: v1

breaking:
  use:
    - FILE
lint:
  use:
    - DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as documented for me. I'm starting with this tree:

```
.
├── acme
│   └── weather
│       └── v1
│           └── weather.proto
└── buf.gen.yaml
```

My buf.gen.yaml:

```
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: false
plugins:
  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/java:v25.1
    out: gen
```

My acme/weather/v1/weather.proto:

```
syntax="proto3";

option java_package="com.acme.weather.v1";
option java_multiple_files=true;
option java_outer_classname="WeatherProto";

package acme.weather.v1;

message WeatherMessage {}
```

`buf generate` generates a class `com.acme.weather.v1.WeatherProto`.

Now with managed mode enabled:

```
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
# ...
```

And the options in acme/weather/v1/weather.proto commented out:

```
syntax="proto3";

// option java_package="com.acme.weather.v1";
// option java_multiple_files=true;
// option java_outer_classname="WeatherProto";
// ...
```

`buf generate` generates the same class `com.acme.weather.v1.WeatherProto`. Managed mode simply sets the options, but does not make any other modifications.